# Xpath: Get all text until a node

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

i have following xml:

```
<div>
    Text i want
    <divider></divider>
    Text i dont want
</div>
```

I want all text in div before the appareance of the divider.
(Under the divider is the signature from a user of a forum)

How does the xpath look like to get the Text I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this `div/divider[1]/preceding-sibling::text()`

as `preceding-sibling` get all the siblings before some node, this is exactly you will need

you can change the `div/divider[1]` part to the right divider element you want.